# RabbitMQ Message Broker with node?

Tags: express, rabbitmq, messagebroker

I moved the our .Net platform from SQL Server to MySQL, to let my technologies communication easy how I can use communication via message bus (rabbitmq) using node, please help?

Comment: Hi, in rabbitmq have a tutorial how can implement RMQ with Nodejs 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html, I will create a gist

Comment: I create a Gist with sample code
https://gist.github.com/kiramishima/07bb633706d5cf72afde54479f8806a4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get answers I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Then head to [Google](https://google.com) and look up RabbitMQ. You'll find a plethora of tutorials that will guide you step by step.

If you've already done all this, then please extrapolate on your question. Give us details on what is causing you problems and where you're stuck.

I hope this doesn't come off as rude, your question is just too broad to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but yes I searched and tried all the stuff regarding RabbitMQ.

Comment: Where did you get stuck on? What confused you? What couldn't you get working?

Comment: But my question is if We moved  .Net platform from MS SQL to MySQL. Now I want a Node application which uses RabbitMQ to communicate with my .Net technologies .

Comment: You could implement rabbit into your .net applications: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html